# How can I call one function when activete or inactivate a jquery ui accordion?

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

My problem is: I want to change my button height when I active my accordion and when I inactive it, and I don't know how can I do that.

I already know how to set my button height via jquery using another button click

```
$("#button1")
    .button()
    .click(function () {
        $("#button2").height(140)
    });
```

and I just want to change it when I activate or inactivate my accordion.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accordion` has a `change` event which is triggered everytime the accordion state is changed. If the accordion is animated, the event will be triggered upon completion of the animation; otherwise, it is triggered immediately. You can use that to call your function.

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
   change: function(event, ui) { 
       //Call your function here 
       $("#button2").height(140);//Or whatever
   }
});
```